# Triple nested rxjs subscription. Having trouble w/ mergeMap

Tags: angular, api, rest, rxjs

When I try using mergeMap, the debugger doesn't trigger in its expression.  I have to call these api's one after another.

```
this.apiService.httpGet(API_URLS.getStats"/statistics?lang=en&region=us").pipe(first()).subscribe((teamStats: any) => {
this.apiService.httpGet(API_URLS.getATS').pipe(first()).subscribe((atsPayload: any) => {
this.apiService.httpGet(API_URLS.getGameHistory").pipe(first()).subscribe((gameHistory: any) => {
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: If yours inner observable don't depend from outer observable use forkJoin, else use switchMap, to get an unique subscription

Comment: Could you show the mergeMap you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: If you want to make 3 simultaneous call and use their result, you can use forkjoin followed by switchMap:

```
forJoin([
  this.apiService.httpGet(API_URLS.getStats/statistics?lang=en&region=us),
  this.apiService.httpGet(API_URLS.getATS),
  this.apiService.httpGet(API_URLS.getGameHistory)
]).pipe(
  switchMap(([result1, result2, result3])=> this.apiService.httpGet('finalCall', result1, result2, result3))
).subscribe((finalResult) => {});
```

2: I you need the previous call result for the next one :

```
this.apiService.httpGet(API_URLS.getStats"/statistics?lang=en&region=us").pipe(
  switchMap((result1) => this.apiService.httpGet(API_URLS.getATS)),
  switchMap((result2) => this.apiService.httpGet(API_URLS.getGameHistory))
).subscribe((result3) => {})
```

3: I the last 2 calls depends onthe result of the first call :

```
this.apiService.httpGet(API_URLS.getStats/statistics?lang=en&region=us).pipe(
  switchMap((stats) => forkJoin([
    of(stats),
    this.apiService.httpGet(API_URLS.getATS),
    this.apiService.httpGet(API_URLS.getGameHistory)
]))
)
.subscribe([stats, secondCall, thirdCall]);
```

Comment: I need to depend on EVERY result of the previous call. That's why i'm having trouble w/ 3 nested

Comment: I need the return values from the subscription for each call.  Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Is API_URLS.getATS call depends on API_URLS.getStats. And API_URLS.getGameHistory depends on API_URLS.getATS ?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. So now what?

Comment: I just updated my response, what about the second proposition ? Is it good ? Do you need something else ?

Comment: Hi, have you stille the problem ?

Comment: no. no problem at all